# Computation Sharing Among Multiple EC2 Instances on AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, dispy

I am working on problem where computational power required to be split across multiple EC2 instances.

I am considering matrix multiplication program , for example huge matrix with thousands of rows and column requires GB's of ram and computation power.

I have amazon EC2 instances (Free eligible) with approx. 800 MB of ram. I am looking forward to work on distribution of computation across multiple EC2 Instances.

I am not sure but Elastic load balancer is something with network traffic load balancer please correct if I am wrong.

I found python **Dispy module** which used for computation distribution and parallel processing.

Can anyone please guide on whether there is any other way to implement it ?

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to see if your computation can be parallelized. Some things necessarily depend on the previous iteration like Method 3 of calculating the nth fib number: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/

In this case, there's no point in trying to use extra computers.

If you can parallelize the task, see if you can use Map Reduce -
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce

AWS has tools for the job - https://aws.amazon.com/emr/